# Can Botium CLI generate Botium test scripts out of convo files and utterances?

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot, botium-box

I want to use Botium for creating chatbot test scripts.

For that I will define Botium convo and utterance files.

Can I activate the CLI (or other Botium api) to parse the Botium files and generate expanded test scripts out of those files?
I want the generated files to include just bot and user texts without reference to other files of partial scripts and without reference to utterances file.

For example, if my *hello.convo.txt* file is:

```
TC01 - Greeting
#me
HELLO_UTT
#bot
Hello, meat bag! How can I help you ?
```

And the *hello_utt.utterances.txt* is:

```
HELLO_UTT
hello bot!!!!
hi bot!
```

I want to activate Botium to generate expanded test scrips.

First test:

```
TC01 - Greeting -1
#me
hello bot!!!!
#bot
Hello, meat bag! How can I help you ?
```

Second test:

```
TC01 - Greeting -2
#me
hi bot!
#bot
Hello, meat bag! How can I help you ?
```

Does it supported by Botium?

Comment: not sure what you want to do. pls add an example to your question.

Comment: @FlorianTreml - added example above. Please see if you know the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default behaviour of Botium CLI to do this kind of expansion on the fly, when runnning the tests - the scripts will be compiled in-memory to exactly what you described.
Currently there is no option to dump this in-memory representation back to disk.